# ttyACM0 stop streaming after some time

Tags: serial-port, arduino

I have an arduino device that read a light sensor which then the result can be stream trough its USB port. on Windows, using a software called `Serial Osciloscope` I am able to read the data sent by the device. however when I run

```
sudo cat /dev/ttyACM0
```

it's keep stopped after displaying some data (approx. 450 line).

please help me, any help would be really appreciated.

thanks in advance.

PS: here is the output of the command

```
...
0,0,0,0,0.000000,0.000000
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,1,2,4,2,0,0,0
1,0,0,4,2,4,0,0,0,0,3,6,4,0,0,0
0,0,0,2,0,0,0,1,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,4,0.000000,0.000000
4,4,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,3
1,12,2,10,3,0,0,0,7,2,1,0,5,0,0,1
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0.000000,0.000000
6,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,2,4,1,3,3
0,0,5,0,0,1,0,5,2,9,3,4,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
# hang on this line.
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting instead. http://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: @muru: I have edited my question, please check again. thank you

Answer (score 2):

solved by adding udev rules from the following link https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/49-teensy.rules

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="16c0", ATTRS{idProduct}=="04[789B]?", ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="16c0", ATTRS{idProduct}=="04[789A]?", ENV{MTP_NO_PROBE}="1"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="16c0", ATTRS{idProduct}=="04[789ABCD]?", MODE:="0666"
KERNEL=="ttyACM*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="16c0", ATTRS{idProduct}=="04[789B]?", MODE:="0666"
```

save as `/etc/udev/rules.d/49-teensy.rules`

Comment: I am having exact same issue but the solution does seems to work for me, any suggestions around the same ?